# Angular invoke TS method by pressing button, attaching rows to table dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I'm trying to create a button, by pressing it should dynamically add rows to the table. However when I try to call the function in TS (`save_row()`), it throws error.

How can I call the function in TS/how can I dynamicall append the rows by pressing the button?

HTML:

```
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
<tr>
   <th>GEOGRAPHY</th>
   <th>COUNTRY</th>
   <th>STATE</th>
   <th>REGULATION</th>
   <th>SMS</th>
   <th>WEB</th>
   <th>EMAIL</th>
   <th>OPERATION</th>
</tr>
</thead>
   <tbody #ir>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

TypeScript:

```
var d=geo_Value;
var len=d.length;       
var  row = this.renderer.createElement('tr'); 
const col=this.renderer.createElement('td');
row.appendChild(col);  

col.outerHTML ="<tr id='row"+len+"'><td 
id='name_row"+geo_Value+"'>"+cou_Value+"</td><input type='button' 
id='save_button' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row("+len+")'> 
</td></tr>";

this.renderer.appendChild(this.ir.nativeElement,row);
let idGet=document.querySelectorAll('#save_button');
var myMessage = "it's working";

function save_row(a) {
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: onclick=saverow("+len+") not calling the method function saverow(a)

Comment: did you check the developer console,it might be throwing some error.

Comment: Ya i checked it.

Comment: Onclick event not triggering

Comment: I've changed question to be clear, however you can improve the post by attaching the code that should be working. If You add required JS libraries, the code can be changed into HTML/JS snippet after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angular ,event binding should be like this

```
id='save_button' value='Save' class='save' (onclick)='save_row("+len+")'>
```

You are missing brackets.

Comment: It's not working because we are appending using js script  event binding technique using native element. (click) is a      typescript event binding method. So ts technique not working inside js.  So the method not calling.